# How to install Mercusys wifi adapter?

Tags: linux, usb, virtualbox, drivers

I am running Kali Linux as a virtual machine in VirtualBox. I have a wifi adapter from Mercusys which I would like to install, but I don't really know how to go about this. The model of wifi adapter I have is Mercusys AC650.
I believe I need to install the Oracle VM VirtualBox Extansion pack 7.0.8r156879. But I don't know where to go from here.

Any help anyone could give me would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If using a wireless adapter for Kali, almost for sure you wish to use the penetration tools.

(1) Kali is unfriendly to begin with and driver installation is also unfriendly. Drivers must be compliant with Kali Linux.

(2) You will almost certainly wish to use Monitor Mode.

(3) For a Kali VM, you need a USB wireless card.  You need to use USB Pass Through (Host VM setting for the Guest Machine) and also need Guest Extensions installed.

Here is a good list of compliant USB Cards:

[Kali USB Wireless](https://www.kalilinux.in/2022/04/wifi-adapter-for-kali-linux.html)

Your card is not on this compliant list, so very likely there is no driver for that card.

I use a Panda USB wireless adapter and it installs and works, and supports monitor mode.

Chipset is important but most cards that support Kali have supported chipsets

Posted from my Kali 2023.2 VM.

Answer (score 0):

**To add a USB Device to the Virtual Machine**

- Download and install the
  [Extensions Pack](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)
- Run VirtualBox and right-click on the virtual machine and select
  Settings
- Click on USB in the left-side menu
- Ensure that "Enable USB Controller" is checked and enable
  USB 2.0 (since your device is USB2)
- In the "USB device filters" section, click on the "add USB devices"
  icon with a `+` sign on it to see the list of the available devices
- Click on the USB device you want to attach to the virtual machine
- click on the OK button to save the current settings.

**To remove a USB device from a virtual machine**

- In VirtualBox right-click the virtual machine and select Settings
- Click "USB" in the left-side menu and go to the "USB device filters"
  section
- Click on the USB device name in the list to select it
- Click on the Remove selected USB filter icon (the one with a cross sign)
- Click OK.